# Is it possible to expose TCP Openshift Service using routes with SNI?

Tags: kubernetes, tcp, routes, openshift

Is it possible to expose TCP Openshift Service using routes with SNI?
I am trying to have a TCP service in Openshift be exposed to outside the cluster with SNI. This article goes through some general idea of it. https://blog.zhaw.ch/icclab/openshift-custom-router-with-tcpsni-support/

Unfortunately, I am not able to get this working at the moment and the article is dated so I am not sure if it is the best resource to use at the moment. Does anyone have any other resources?

Answer (score 3):

NodePort Service is the way when an application needs to expose TCP protocol outside OpenShift cluster.

Here is the limitation of the Ingress Controller (Router) *1

> This is limited to HTTP, HTTPS using SNI, and TLS using SNI, which is
> sufficient for web applications and services that work over TLS with
> SNI.

*1: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.11/networking/configuring_ingress_cluster_traffic/configuring-ingress-cluster-traffic-ingress-controller.html#nw-using-ingress-and-routes_configuring-ingress-cluster-traffic-ingress-controller